# numeros primos aleatorios em C

Tags: c

Tenho de fazer um programa capaz de gerar de forma automática e aleatória 100 números inteiros positivos entre 0 e 1000 e que apresente na consola a soma e média dos primos existentes no conjunto criado.

O meu código esta assim e quando quero mostrar um numero primo aparece muitos numeros repetidos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int number, i, counter, sum, num_divider = 0, divider;
    float media;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        number = rand() % 1000;

         for(divider = 1; divider <= 1000; divider++)
            {
              if(number % divider == 0)
              {
                num_divider++;
              }



                if(num_divider < 2)
                {
                    sum += number;
                     printf("%02dº gerado %d\n", (i + 1), number);

                    printf("%d", number);

                    counter++;
                }

                num_divider = 0; 
            }

    }

    media = sum / counter;

    puts("");
    printf(" the sum is: %d\n", sum);
    printf(" the average is: %.0f\n", media);       

}
```

Comment: Isto provavelmente já foi respondido em uma destas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%5d%20primo

Comment: O titulo que tem induz em erro, pois da a ideia que quer gerar apenas numeros primos de forma aleatoria. Sugiro que o troque e o coloque mais apropriado em relação ao que está a ser realmente perguntado.

Comment: Para evitar a repetição você tem que guardar (por ex. em um array) todos os primos já gerados e a cada novo primo compará-lo com os já registrados. Se ainda não constar da relação então acrescente-o senão gere um novo.